# How to generate a warning/error when using non-string-variables inside string interpolation?

Tags: string, typescript, substring, concatenation, tostring

TypeScript does not produce any errors for the following code:

```js
const maybe_a_string: undefined | string = undefined;
const false_or_string: false | string = false;

// I'd like the following to produce an error/warning...
const message_string = `Some readable string info should be here: ${maybe_a_string}  ${false_or_string}`;
```

Is there some kind of setting I can turn on, or simple alternative ways to write the last line that will warn me about trying to use non-string variables inside strings like this?  (but without needing to add extra lines of code for every sub-string to be asserted individually)

I guess it treats them as fine because some types like bools, numbers and misc objects have a `.toString()` method...

But especially in the case of `undefined` (which actually doesn't have a .toString() method) - it's quite common for you to have a bug there, as the only time you really want to see the string "undefined" inside another string is for debugging purposes.  But there's a lot of these bugs out there in the wild where end users are seeing stuff like "hello undefined" unintentionally.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a linter, but it's a hard sort of thing to search for, a rule may not exist yet

Comment: It follows the same rules as `"" + expr`, which are well-defined.

Comment: _But there's a lot of these bugs out there in the wild_ - there are no wild, it is our code we write, you can fix it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would handle this by making the string template into a function.  That way you can specify that the arguments must be strings.

```
const createMessageString = (first: string, second: string): string => {
    return `Some readable string info should be here: ${first}  ${second}`;
}

const message_string = createMessageString( maybe_a_string, false_or_string );
// will give an error unless types are refined
```

Answer (score 0):

Vote for https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30239 [Restrict template literal interpolation expressions to strings]

Additionally, you can try workarounds from the issue comments.